# ExternalLoginConfirmation returns null after facebook successful login

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5

Implementing Facebook login in MVC 5 template, had added the app Id and secret code.

Initially login was failing as it was returning null

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    // Crashes on this line
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

After searching came across a solution which says to replace existing ExternalLoginCallback method with this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var result = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        if (result == null || result.Identity == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (idClaim == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var login = new UserLoginInfo(idClaim.Issuer, idClaim.Value);
        var name = result.Identity.Name == null ? "" : result.Identity.Name.Replace(" ", "");

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { UserName = name });
        }
    }
```

Now that issue is solved but when I try to Associate your Facebook account. 
You've successfully authenticated with Facebook. Please enter a user name for this site below and click the Register button to finish logging in.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Here comes the error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

On debugging the username come then too can't figure it out that why its throwing exception.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 5):

I think when it gets to `GetExternalLoginInfoSync` that returns null.

I had the same problem and here is how I managed to fix it and get the email from Facebook.

- Update following NuGet Pacakges

  - `Microsoft.Owin` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` to version `3.1.0-rc1`

Then add the following code to the `Identity Startup` class

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "your app id",
            AppSecret = "your app secret",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name",
            Scope = { "email" }
        };

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

This is the definition class for `FacebookBackChannelHandler()`:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Replace the RequestUri so it's not malformed
        if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the job for me, gets the user's email too

Answer (score 3):

just update

> **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.0.1** to
>
> **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.1.0**

worked for me.. but small issue you will not get email on next page after successfull login. that was fine for me.

Comment: I already had this - I created a new MVC project with identity - and this stll happens.

Answer (score 0):

Might be it can help some one:

```
var option = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
option.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("fbAppId");
option.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("fbAppSecret");
option.Scope.Add("email");
option.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=name,email";
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(option);
```

I am getting everything, Name as well as Email

Answer (score 0):

You have to update facebook version, you can use this code 
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Version 3.1.0-rc1