# Social Login of facebook not working in ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I am going through a tutorial to implement facebook social log in my sample web site. Below are the steps I did.

1. Pointed my localhost application to https and allowed fake SSL in VS.
2. Created a web app in facebook developer web site and noted down the secret key and id.
3. Added my application localhost URL in the URL section of the dashboard in facebook
4. I added key and id in the starup.Auth.cs file in my ASP.Net MVC-5 project .

**Behavour:** Now when I run my application from local host (https) and `click Register` then I see the `facebook sign in button`. Also when I click that button a facebook pop up comes with **"Sample App" wants to access your facebook data**. So far so good. But as I say `YES` to it nothing happens after that. I get redirected to the log in page. and the URL is `https://localhost:44393/Account/Login#_=_`

**Expected Behaviour:** For the tutorial that I am following after doing above steps one message comes on tutors screen as "Facebook has authenticated.... Enter you email to continue". Something like this. Can some one please guide me here why I am not getting same message and why I am not able to use social log in. I have tried to follow all the steps.

**Expected Screenshot from tutorial**
[image]

Is there any other steps I need to do in facebook developer dashboard?

**EDIT 1 :**

In the facebook developer dashboard for my app in the Facbook Login Tab->Settings : I see below message.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I debugged and found that **returnURL** is **null** when I click on facebook log in button.

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, After research I found out that I need to install package `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` from nuget package manager. After this everything worked fine.

Comment: I have the above error - and this package is already installed. This happens if i create a vanilla MVC project with Individual Authentication.

Comment: Try uninstalling that and installing again. Just saying.

Comment: It's in a brand new vanilla mvc application - with identity selected. Uninstalling and re-installing in a brand new app makes zero sense.

Comment: I see.. Let me know once you find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try - seems to be to do with the Facebook 2.4 API update.

Answer (score 1):

Simply update the Windows.Owin.Security.Facebook to latest version(3.1.0) 
further in facebook application update the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" to "http://localhost:xxxx/signin-facebook" (in my case) every thing works...

OR

Please see the link [ExternalLoginConfirmation returns null after facebook succesful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540678/externalloginconfirmation-returns-null-after-facebook-succesful-login?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You also may need to add your URI localhost to Valid OAuth... on Facebook app to return your application when login success.

Comment: I also thought so. As a matter of fact some time back when I was implementing google log in I had to add REDIRECT URI in the settings of google dashboard. But for facebook I did not put anything. And even in the tutorial they have not mentioned about putting any value there.

Comment: Ideally, I should put. But I am beginner and I don't know much how under the hood everything works.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 07/18/2018:**

In my case I had to update nuget packages:

- Microsoft.Owin to version 4.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb to version 4.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security to version 4.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies to version 4.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook to version 4.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth to version 4.0.0
- Newtonsoft.Json to version 11.0.2

big help for me was to check Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc) where I saw actual reason for HTTP 500 when facebook redirected back to my site with url: http://localhost:7566/signin-facebook

Error log was:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileLoadException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, 
Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler. 
<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine] 
(TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at 

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& 
initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at 
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationHandler. 
<InvokeReplyPathAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
...
```

after this I updated also Newtonsoft.Json and facebook authentication through OWIN started to work for me.