# Facebook authentication not working (asp mvc 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have issue. When I deployed my project, after a few hours I have got a null from AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(). But when I recycle my site, facebook authentication works again during a few hours. I have tried all tips. I updated all OWIN packages to version 3.1.0. Version of API 2.5. Please help me.

Comment: Install package `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` from nuget package manager.

Comment: I installed before, but authorization works only a few hours.

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510281/social-login-of-facebook-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-5-project/43511619

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried it too.

Comment: I too have the same issue. I had also installed Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, but facebook login is not working. However, I created a MVC Core demo application and followed steps in the basic tutorial and facebook authentication is working in that. It is really annoying that the tutorials are not updated for the changes in OWIN middleware/facebook.